# Import LESS file only for one page

Tags: css, less

I have main `all.less` file, where I'm including all other less files

e.g.

```
@import "scaffolding.less";
@import "type.less";
@import "code.less";
@import "grid.less";
@import "homepage.less";
```

So my question is.

Is it possible to get`"homepage.less"` only in homepage (importing it in `all.less`).

Please Note that I don't want to attach it directly in the html file.

Thanks

Comment: You're using `.less` files in production? It's not the best idea - the whole point is to render them out to css when in live situation, meaning beforehand

Comment: No I compile all.less file in main.css, that's why I have a problem attaching homepage.less only in one html page, as importing it in all.less make it to render in all pages, not just in homepage

Comment: Why would you want each page to have its own css file?  The idea here is to have your site's css cached for the entire site, so load time is fast between pages.  If you are wanting to separate that per page, then all that says is you have very poorly written css, and you are not reusing any of your styles correctly.  I would suggest you take a look at your css and ask yourself why your 'homepage.less' file contains so much unique code, and not reusing whats already on the site.

Comment: You can't use common styles if you have certain PSD file and your client wants you to follow strongly to that design. In my case homepage is wholly different from other pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your homepage use:

```
<body class="homepage">
```

And then in your Less files:

```
.homepage {
  @import "homepage.less";
}
```

The above still compiles all your code in a single file. Your compiled CSS code will have a larger number of bytes, but you can cache the same file for all your pages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think this is the best solution for now.

Answer (score 1):

If your homepage is seperate html file, then you should include separate css file to it.

I would suggest you to rethink your design. Because it seems that your css code is not so reusable. [Here](https://smacss.com/book/) is a very good and free book that will teach you the concepts.

Comment: I have certain design given from my client, and in my case the homepage is wholly different from other pages. Also just changing design is not solution to the problem, so I was wondering if that's possible. Btw thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

That does not seem to be possible directly as all the `less` will eventually be compiled to `css` before being given to a page. Probably you need to create a separate file with a name like `all_homepage.less` for that purpose?

Comment: hmmm, in that case I've to create separate css files for each page I want to attach a separate less file, and compile corresponding less file in corresponding css, is it a good idea?

Comment: May be, that depends on the number of pages you have.

Comment: With a main large CSS file (cached) on all pages and a second smaller CSS file with per page code you will need two http requests. When you combine all is the same file you will need only one http request but will have to load a larger number of bytes. In most situations the last option is the fastest. Only when you have a very large number of `per page` code, loading the larger number of bytes will be slower than the extra http request.