# less.modifyVars not working in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, less, dotless

I have read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn463774.aspx) tutorial for working with `Less` in Asp.Net MVC5.

To integrate LESS in ASP.NET MVC, I download and install the [dotless](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotless/) NuGet package.

And then added this bundle:

```
var lessBundle = new Bundle("~/Less").Include("~/Content/Less/*.less");
lessBundle.Transforms.Add(new LessTransform());
lessBundle.Transforms.Add(new CssMinify());
bundles.Add(lessBundle);
```

Here is the `LessTransform`:

```
public class LessTransform : IBundleTransform
{
  public void Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response)
  {
    response.Content = dotless.Core.Less.Parse(response.Content);
    response.ContentType = "text/css";
  }
}
```

So far so good. Everything works as it is expected.

Here is the part from my `.less` file:

```
@CustomMessageBackgroundColor: #65B6A7;

div.custom-dialog {
    ...
    background: @CustomMessageBackgroundColor;
}
```

Now, I want to change the value of this variable from `.js` file dynamically:

```
less.modifyVars({ '@CustomMessageBackgroundColor': 'blue' });
less.refreshStyles();
```

But, this is not working.
I have read all SO questions and as I understand this must work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up two different LESS compiler implementations.

Your javascript call might work if you were using [less.js](http://lesscss.org) in the browser to compile your stylesheets, but since you're compiling them on the server side with [dotless](http://github.com/dotless/dotless), what you are getting to the browser is the compiled CSS which no longer contains the variables -- they are already expanded at that point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I must use `Less.js` instead of `dotless`? To tell the truth I want to chnage ui theme based on user choice. So, I have decide to use Less.

Comment: *Must* is a strong word. Dotless supports dynamic variables via query string parameters, but then bundling becomes a bit problematic. It all depends on what you really need to accomplish, but might be that less.js is your best bet here. :)

Comment: I havemade another investiagtion. And found that Web Essentials already supported .less files. But, I don't know how can I chnage the variables from javascript? Do you have any practice with that?

Comment: If you preprocess them before they are sent to the client, you can not change the variables at the client's side.

Comment: I got it. Thanks. I have misunderstood this process.

Comment: according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30574701/1596547) you should be able to set variable values from query string parameters. I have not tested this solution. Notice that Less uses Lazy loading and last declaration wins for variables, so the parameter should be injected at the end of the source to generate the same affect as  modifyVars does.

Comment: I know -- it was my answer! -- but if you use Bundle Transformer, it doesn't quite work that way, because you never go through the Dotless HttpHandler. Also, as of Dotless 1.5, values from query string variables are appended to the source, so you can have default values and override them with query string variables.