# (AngularJS) Only one less file for entire Website

Tags: css, angularjs, less

I am a beginner with AngularJS and I have a little problem, I installed grunt-contrib-less to support less files instead css but now I have to declare all less styles that will be compiled into only one css file.

But my problem is normally when I'm using less, I write some code for a specific page, and here I have to write the style code for all pages. This is confusing and not really maintanable so is there a best practice to organize less styles?

I tought that there may be multiple solution:

1. Apply a class to body tag and change it with I don't know what
   (controller, services or other)
   ([Import LESS file only for one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207921/import-less-file-only-for-one-page))
2. Generate multiple css file depending which style is compiled (but I can't do this because I can't configure grunt correctly)
3. Do this with DOM manipulation (but it don't find it beautifull because I think Angular must have a good way to solve that problem)

Could you explain me how to have different style for differents views ? I don't want to have the same style for all links in all views and without create hundreds classes I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by adding specific class on body tag depending the route.
I put a variable in rootScope called 'pageStyle' with correspond to the classname that I want. This variable is updated automatically when route change (see run function). There is an event when the route change ($stateChangeSuccess or $routeChangeSuccess depending if you are using ngRoute or -angularui-routeur).

In my case i would like to add the name of the route but you can do it with the controller name or something else.

**Here is an example**

This is the routes :

```
angular
  .module('frontApp', [])
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $mdThemingProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: '../views/home.html',
        controller: function ($scope) {
          $scope.msg = 'Xavier';
        }
      })
      .state('form', {
        url: '/form',
        templateUrl: '../views/form.html',
        controller: 'FormCtrl'
      });
  }])
```

And in the run function you will see the event bound to adapt the class when route change :

```
  .run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.pageStyle = '';
    // Watch state and set controller name in pageStyle variable when state change
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (toState && toState.name && typeof toState.name === 'string'){
        $rootScope.pageStyle = toState.name;
      } else {
        $rootScope.pageStyle = '';
      }
    });
  });
```

Extra informations :

- Note that the event called when route change is different if you are using ngroute. use "$routeChangeSuccess" if you use ngRoute and "$stateChangeSuccess" if you choose to use angular-ui-routeur
- If you want to add the controller name instead the route name simply use the follow and replace 'ctrl' with you controller suffixe:

  ```
  if (toState && toState.controller && typeof toState.controller !== 'function'){
      $rootScope.pageStyle = toState.controller.toLowerCase().replace('ctrl','');
  }
  ```

Hope it help someone else

Answer (score 2):

Use directive

and add whatever variables/code/logic you want to add

> HTML template(directive) of style can be added to your view  and after compile you will get different ui for all your views

for reference read

[angular directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: I found another solution but I don't know if there is a better way to do that But thank you for you answer it help me to see which component to use before founding the above solution.